# c# in VS2005: what do the following types default to in C#?

Tags: c#, default-value

For C# in VS2005, what will be value of variables of the following types if they are simply declared and not assigned to any value?  ie. What are their default values?

```
int
bool
string
char
enum
```

Comment: 30 seconds in VS to find out? Maybe a minute. And `enum` isn't a type.

Comment: @aakashM: the selected answer provides a lot more than what could be learnt in VS in 30 seconds.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If they're used locally (i.e. they're not members of a class or struct) they won't *have* default values. You won't be able to use them until they're assigned a value (unless you explicitly "new them up").

If they're *not* used locally, they'll default to `0`, `false`, `null`, and `'\0'`.

**Edit:** You've added `enum` to your list. `enums` default to a value of 0 because they use an `int` by default behind the scenes. So whatever enumerate is declared as 0 for the `enum` (typically the first enumerate, but that's overridable) will be the default. If you don't *have* a 0 value enumerate for whatever reason, then you'll have an invalid value for your `enum` as the default value.

> *Please explain. I am talking about declaring the variables inside the scope of a class or method.* – Craig Johnston

I told a little white lie to point out how the compiler works. If you declare a local variable, the compiler will not compile if you try to use it without having first explicitly assigning a value to that variable; that includes `null` for reference types.

For example:

```
public void Foo()
{
   int bar;
   int barPlus5 = bar + 5; // Compiler Error!
}
```

*Technically*, `bar` still has a default value of 0, but because the C# compiler will not allow you to use that default value in a locally scoped variable, a locally scoped variable effectively doesn't have a default value. `<Ben Kenobi>`So what I told you was true, from a certain point of view.`</Ben Kenobi>`.

There are exceptions to the rule: out parameters get a pass because the compiler enforces that an out parameter must be assigned by a method before it returns, and you can do `int bar = new int();` to get the default value, since that's technically an assignment.

Now, if you declare a variable as a member of a class or a struct such as follows:

```
public class Foo
{
    public int Bar {get;set;}
    public Foo() { } 
}
```

And then you instantiate Foo somewhere, Bar will have a default value of 0.

For example:

```
var foo = new Foo();
Console.WriteLine(foo.Bar); // output: 0
```

Comment: Please explain. I am talking about declaring the variables inside the scope of a class or method.

Answer (score 7):

Here's what default value for each type you've mentioned would be.

```
int = 0  
bool = false  
string = null  
char = '\0'  
enum = 0    //behind the scenes enum is int
```

Taking this forward, at runtime if you wish to capture default value of any type then you can use `default` statement in C#  and simply call it as following.

```
//This will print 0 on screen.
Console.WriteLine(default(int));
```

Generally, this is used in generics for identifying default values of generic type arguments, where the type is only known at runtime.

Comment: I like the addition of `default`, which I totally neglected in my answer. I'd give you another +1 if I could..

Answer (score 0):

MSDN article - [Value Types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s1ax56ch.aspx).

> All value types implicitly declare a
>   public parameterless instance
>   constructor called the "default
>   constructor". The default constructor
>   returns a zero-initialized instance
>   know as the default value for the
>   value type.
>
> In case of local variables (Value or
>   Reference Types) in C#, they must be
>   initialized before they are used.

MSDN Article - [Types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173104.aspx)

> A type that is defined as a class,
>   delegate, array, or interface is a
>   reference type. At run time, when you
>   declare a variable of a reference
>   type, the variable contains the value
>   **null** until you explicitly create an
>   instance of the object by using the
>   new operator, or assign it an object
>   that has been created elsewhere by
>   using new.